# Trying to proxy a websocket and connection is not established in setupProxy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I have my React app, which is setup by setupProxy.js, and it is suppose to proxy my ws backend. But somehow the connection is not establised, however http and https requests work just fine. attaching code example: 
**setupProxy.js**

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware')

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use(
        '/sockets',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'ws://localhost:8080',
            pathRewrite: (path) => path.replace('/sockets', ''),
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true
        })
    );

    app.use(
        '/hello', 
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'http://localhost:8080/hello',
            pathRewrite: (path) => path.replace('/hello', ''),
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true
        })
    )
}
```

**App.tsx**

```js
import React from 'react';

const App: React.FC = () => {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    new WebSocket(`ws://${window.location.host}/sockets`);
    fetch('/hello').then(value => value.json()).then(res => console.log('response: ', res))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      Hello World
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**backend/index.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => res.send({hello: 'hello'}))

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.disconnect();
});

server.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:8080');
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: and how your setupProxy.js gets in the game?

Comment: what did you mean I didn't understand, in this line ````ws://${window.location.host}/sockets```` I'm requesting the proxy to connect to the backend

Comment: how is `setupProxy.js` refered in your code?

Comment: It is triggered by react-scripts in the setup of the app

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: yeah it seems that the middleware requires a http request and then the socket connects

Comment: I have the same doubt can some one share an example